# Ruby pig latin translator for multiple words

Tags: ruby

I'm working on creating a pig latin translator in ruby. It works for most words, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work with more than one word at a time. So for example when you just put in the word "apple" you get "appleay" but if more than one word is inputted it does not translate them. I've been searching around for a solution but have come up empty. A few other threads on here have been really helpful in getting me this far. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I've also added in a couple of exceptions in the if/else statement to allow for the proper pig latin translation of "quiet" and "square", where "qu" is considered a consonant.

Thanks in advance for any help guys!

```
def translate (word)
  alpha = ('a'..'z').to_a
  vowels = %w[a e i o u]
  consonants = alpha - vowels

  if vowels.include?(word[0..0])
    word + 'ay'
  elsif consonants.include?(word[0..0]) && consonants.include?(word[1..1])
    word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
  elsif word[0..1] == "qu" 
    word[2..word.length]+"quay"
  elsif word[0..2] == "squ"
     word[3..word.length]+"squay"
  else consonants.include?(word[0])
    word[1..-1] + word[0..0] + 'ay'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
Alpha = ('a'..'z').to_a
Vowels = %w[a e i o u]
Consonants = Alpha - Vowels

def translate(word)
  if Vowels.include?(word[0])
    word + 'ay'
  elsif Consonants.include?(word[0]) && 
    Consonants.include?(word[1])
    word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
  elsif word[0..1] == "qu" 
    word[2..-1]+"quay"
  elsif word[0..2] == "squ"
     word[3..-1]+"squay"
  else Consonants.include?(word[0])
    word[1..-1] + word[0..0] + 'ay'
  end
end

puts "Enter some text to translate"
text = fgets
puts text.split.map(&method(:translate)).join(' ')
```

Comment: Where would I put that code to get the right result? Putting it before or after the if/else statement gives me an "stack level too deep" error.

Comment: You would put it outside of the body of the method (i.e. on the last line of your program), with the variable `text` being a string containing the input word(s) to translate.

Comment: So before the last "end" of the method? And for the "text variable, it should just be left as is? Do I need to direct the input from the method there at all?

Comment: Updated the answer to make it clearer how to piece the two together.

Answer (score 0):

what about breaking it down into multiple methods? i.e a method that breaks the string into words and then sends those words off to another method for translating before joining them to together and giving an output.

```
def translator(sentence)
  words_to_translate = sentence.split(" ")
  translated_words = words_to_translate.map {|word| translate_word(word)}
  translated_sentence = translated_words.join(" ")
end

def translate_word(word)
  ...code here
  return a word
end
```